# VBA - Regular Expression Replacement Problems

Tags: vba

My Code:

```
    Public Sub IPCheck()
     Dim IP As String

     IP = Regex.IsMatch(TxbLog.Text, "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b")

     If IP = False Then
         MsgBox("IP NOT FOUND")
     Else
         MsgBox("IP FOUND")
         TxbLog.Text = Regex.Replace(TxbLog.Text, IP, " X")
     End If
    End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it isn't replacing the IP with an X and I don't know why. (I've tried swapping the replace line around with the "Not Found" in case I was just being stupid and it still doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsMatch` method returns a `Boolean`, which makes little sense to use as second argument to the `Replace` method later: `True` does not appear in your String, so nothing gets replaced.

Instead use the `Match` method:

```
Public Sub IPCheck()
    Dim IP As String
    Dim match As Match

    match = Regex.Match(TxbLog.Text, "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b")

    If Not match.Success Then
        MsgBox("IP NOT FOUND")
    Else
        IP = match.Groups(0).Value
        MsgBox("IP FOUND: " & IP)
        TxbLog.Text = Regex.Replace(TxbLog.Text, IP, " X")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey so I've just come across a problem, I've come across IP's that aren't all 3 digits then dots, how can I change this:
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
To search for IP's that maybe have 1 or 2 numbers then a dot

Comment: Can you give an example of such an IP that does not work with this regular expression?

Comment: For those the regular expression will [find a match](https://regex101.com/r/boB5j1/2). Just make sure there is a break after the pattern, i.e. there should not be a letter or underscore following the last digit, nor preceding the first digit.

Comment: I need it to now find it and then continue to find them on multiple lines, I heard of .multiline but I think that's outdated and I've heard of \g but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Look into the method [Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) (plural). Loop with `For Each match In Regex.Matches(...)`, ...etc.